# How to configure cni network for kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, calico

In the past, we deployed the k8s cluster with the short command:KUBERNETES_PROVIDER=ubuntu ./kube-up.sh, the default network is flannel.
Now we'd like to isolate service for different user based on calico+namespace, how to configure calico network in shell script ubuntu/config-default.sh ,what does CNI_PLUGIN_EXES mean ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a local cluster setup to test this advice, but I do know that [coreos-kubernetes](https://github.com/coreos/coreos-kubernetes/blob/v0.8.6/multi-node/generic/worker-install.sh#L38) needs the [CNI binaries](https://github.com/containernetworking/cni/releases/tag/v0.5.2) to live in `/opt/cni/bin` or [bad things happen](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/30681).

Thus, I would *guess* `CNI_PLUGIN_EXES` would be `/opt/cni/bin/YOUR_CNI_BINARY` where `YOUR_CNI_BINARY` is the one that Calico expects.